# VIPER design pattern in Swift configuring view

Tags: ios, swift, view, configuration, viper-architecture

I have recently migrated to VIPER and while using this type of architecture came up with such question:

For instance, I have in designs long(2000pt height) UI with over 50 interface elements like labels, buttons, views, collections and so on and I need to add round corners and shadows to them.

Where should I configure its appearance? Should it be in View, or somehow in Presenter?

So far I have extended UIView to create a method to drop shadow.

Right now, what I have in View module is:

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    doctorsNearCollection.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0)
    newsMayBeInterestedCollection.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0)
    recentSavedNewsCollection.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0)
    setupCharts()
    
    scheduleMetting.dropShadow()
    scheduleMetting.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    
    monthlyPerformaceBackground.dropShadow()
    monthlyPerformaceBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    
    firstMeeting.dropShadow()
    firstMeeting.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    firstMeetingNumber.layer.cornerRadius = self.firstMeetingNumber.frame.size.width / 2
    
    secondMeeting.dropShadow()
    secondMeeting.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    secondMeetingNumber.layer.cornerRadius = self.secondMeetingNumber.frame.size.width / 2
    
    thirdMeeting.dropShadow()
    thirdMeeting.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    thirdMeetingNumber.layer.cornerRadius = self.thirdMeetingNumber.frame.size.width / 2
    
    seeAllMeetings.dropShadow()
    seeAllMeetings.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    
    searchForDoctors.dropShadow()
    searchForDoctors.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    
    seeAllSavedNews.dropShadow()
    seeAllSavedNews.layer.cornerRadius = 5
}
```

Is this a good practice?
I'm interested in setting up commonality among the appearance of views as factored out from other methods.  It seems more or less clear to me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never take any view related changes to the presenter. **EVER**. The presenter is just supposed to tell the view that data related processing has been complete. Also i would do all these changes in their respective lazy initializations.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri yes, talking about lazy, that's what I'm also doing, thanks for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As described in https://TheSwiftDev.com/the-ultimate-viper-architecture-tutorial, UI details & constructs must be quarantined in view zone and never appear in presenter zone, because view zone handles/quarantines all UI details/concepts as an internal matter whereas presenter zone handles/quarantines all pure app-domain details/concepts as an internal matter.
- In the spirit of never-say-never, the only time that “rounded corners and shadows” to UI elements would ever be in presenter zone is if the *app-domain* itself of the app was all about being a UI-generator or UI-editor or UI-designer tool, where some downstream(-app's) UI (i.e., not *this* app's UI) is the app-domain of this app.  So unless your app is a UI design environment for UI development, UI stuff never ever gets out of view zone (and even in the exception it is some other app's UI stuff, not this current app's UI stuff).
- Just because some UI-centric code needs to be factored out as commonality among views, that doesn't mean that it gets the VIPER treatment of breaking into the other 4 zones {interactor, presenter, entities, router} as a way of expressing the commonality.  The view zone itself can have layers.  One such layer is an infrastructural library of commonality among 2 or more views.  (Another such layer might be a façade that translates UI-centric events into app-domain-centric events that go interzone over to presenter to handle, not as a UI-centric event, but as an app-domain event independent of how it is represented in the UI.)  If some function, method, procedure, subroutine, or coroutine needs to be factored out as commonality among multiple views within view zone, then keep that factored out function, method, procedure, subroutine, or coroutine in a library within view zone, not any of the other IPER zones.

Comment: Thank you for great answer and nice link to tutorial about VIPER. My question was answered long time ago, and at that time I had little knowledge about VIPER since I've just started learning.